# BindCommand With Parameter ListView ReactiveUI Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am using Reactiveui with xamarin forms. I have Product Categories which is an observable collection getting bound to listview on xaml page. On click of a particular product category I need to get sub categories. The Following is the code of my xaml file, code behind file and the viewmodel file. I cannot get the Id of the product category clicked.

Xaml File

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}" HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="lvProductCategories" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductCategoryId}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell 
                            Text="{Binding CategoryName}">
                        </ImageCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind File

```
public ProductCategoryPage()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = ViewModel = new ProductCategoryPageViewModel();

            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.CMDGetSubProductCategories, page => page.lvProductCategories, vm => vm.SelectedProductCategoryId ,nameof(lvProductCategories.ItemTapped));
}
```

ViewModel File

```
public class ProductCategoryPageViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
            private IProductCategoryService ProductCategoryService;
            public ProductCategoryPageViewModel(IProductCategoryService productCategoryService = null)
            {
                ProductCategoryService = productCategoryService ?? (IProductCategoryService)Splat.Locator.Current.GetService(typeof(IProductCategoryService));
                GetProductCategories();
    
                CMDGetSubProductCategories = ReactiveCommand.Create<int>(x =>
                {
                    GetSubProductCategories(x);
                });
    
               
            }
    
    
            ObservableCollection<ProductCategoryMaster> _productCategories;
            public ObservableCollection<ProductCategoryMaster> ProductCategories
            {
                get => _productCategories;
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _productCategories, value); }
            }
    
            int _selectedProductCategoryId;
            public int SelectedProductCategoryId
            {
                get => _selectedProductCategoryId;
                set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedProductCategoryId, value);
            }
    
            
            public async void GetProductCategories()
            {
                var productCategories = await ProductCategoryService.GetAllProductCategories();
                ProductCategories = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategoryMaster>(productCategories);
            }
    
            public async void GetSubProductCategories(int pcid)
            {
                var productCategories = await ProductCategoryService.GetSubProductCategories(pcid);
                ProductCategories = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategoryMaster>(productCategories);
            }
    
            public ReactiveCommand<int,Unit> CMDGetSubProductCategories { get; }
}
```

I am new to xamarin forms and reactiveui. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem I solved it using the following.

xaml file (added the itemselectedevent)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}" HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="lvProductCategories" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductCategoryId}" ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell 
                            Text="{Binding CategoryName}">
                        </ImageCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Xaml.cs file

```
private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var model = e.SelectedItem as ProducCategoryMaster; 
        var vm = BindingContext as ProductCategoryPageViewModel;
        vm.SelectedProductCategoryId = model.PKProductCategoryId;
}
```

Rest of the code remains same as I have posted in my question.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).